# Locking tables in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, records

How do I lock fields in access so the user is only able to add to table? I want the user to only have access to adding to the table to maintain data integrity.

Comment: it depends. Assuming you take proper precautions, you can simply restrict how forms interact with the data. You can't let them touch the tables directly however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Access 2010 (or later) you can use event-driven Data Macros to restrict what the users can do. To prevent them from deleting records you can use the following Before Delete macro:

[image: BeforeDelete.png]

If you also want to prevent them from editing existing records you can use the following Before Change macro:

[image: BeforeChange.png]

For more information see

[Create a data macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx)

Comment: @user3537383 Nonsense. The `RaiseError` action is available to event-driven Data Macros in Access 2010.