# MS Access 2016 - Prevent users from updating data in queries

Tags: security, ms-access, locking

This seems like a simple question, but Google doesn't seem to want to give me a direct answer.

I've been given an Access 2016 database with some queries that the owner would like his client to use. When a query is run and displays data, the default is that users can make changes to the displayed data and these changes are saved to the underlying table. Is there a way to protect those tables so that they don't change if the user makes changes?

This has the feel of a simple question, but I can't seem to find a way to lock those underlying tables.

Comment: No. If query is editable then the data edits will pass to the table. Don't let users interact with tables and queries, only forms and reports.

Comment: @YouE3K, that's what I've been finding. Thank you.

Comment: June7 already pointed out that Access is not secure--it will not prevent hacks and purposeful changes, especially if someone is very familiar with Access.  However, there are measures that will prevent inadvertent edits and keep a novice user from changing data.  Still interested in alternative techniques?

Comment: [Locking tables in Access 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920764/locking-tables-in-access-2010) might be a duplicate question. Essentially, a separate [AllowInsert] Yes/No field or an [InsertKey] string field is added to a table and changes are only allowed in Data Macros if the "insert field" has the proper value. You can also hide tables, hide Navigation panel, then create read-only Snapshot queries of all tables. Other queries can reference the read only queries just like tables but without being able to change the data. These will NOT prevent intentional changes.

Comment: Have you tried to change the _Recordset Type_ in query design/properties from _Dynaset_ to _Snapshot_?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Before Change Data Macro** as a workaround

Switch table to Design View and create Before Change Macro, like this:

[image: Before Change Data Macro]

This macro will instantly revert any changes that user make at YourField or AnotherField. You can lock selected columns only, if you wish.

Adding new records is unaffected. For more details see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835322.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well, build a report or a continues items form, and have the users launch hat report (or form). If you use a form, then set the edits = no, and your problem is solved.

You might have to change your start-up settings to hide the navigation pane, and hide all queries etc. (but this is quite easy to do).

Thus you provide a menu form, perhaps custom ribbon, or a form hat simply lets the user select the form or report to launch. That way, users can mess around with the actual query, and the resulting report (or form) can be set to not edit data.